# Django REST Framework, setting up Django Storages/S3 Boto to store some media files to the bucket, and some to local storage

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've setup Django Storages/S3 Boto to save user-uploaded files to the s3 bucket, with the settings bellow:

```
# AWS Bucket access keys
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'

# AWS Bucket config stuff
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}

# Media file location
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/'
```

**How would i modify the storage settings/configuration so that i can save some user uploaded files to this S3 bucket, while saving some others to the local file system?**

Currently, my FileField looks like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default='email@email.com')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + '-' + self.file.name
```

my "upload_path" looks like this:

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return instance.email + '/' + filename
```

Comment: Storages just saves the "path" portion in the database field.  The rest is determined based on what your field's "storage" class is, in code.  To do something different, but still utilize the packed, you'd need to write your own Storage backend which uses both s3 & file storage, and a custom format to save the path as in the database to tell yourself which one to use when *reading* the file back out, all proxying calls to the package s3/file classes.  Its all technically possible, but difficult and most definitely not designed to work like this.